# Cannot make Internationalisation works in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

I am following every step in the [Translation document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) of Symfony. But I still cannot make Internationalisation works in Symfony. Instead of translated message I receive the same message. What I am doing wrong? Here is my setup:

1) app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: fa }
```

2) app/parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_user: root
    locale: fa
```

3) Translation file located in src/App/AppBundle/Resources/translations/addproduct.fa.xliff

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Title</source>
                <target>عنوان</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

4) Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("{_locale}/test")
 */
public function Test()
{
    $translated = $this->get('translator')->trans('Title');

    return new Response($translated);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Number 3) should be a file in the `src/App/AppBundle/Resources/translations` directory. The file name needs to follow the `domain.locale.loader` convention as outlined [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations), for example `app.fa.xliff`.
2. If you named the file `app.fa.xliff`, then `'app'` is your domain. You need to reference this domain in the `->trans` method:

`$translated = $this->get('translator')->trans('Title', array(), 'app');`

Comment: I followed the naming convention but I forgot to mention it in my question. (Question updated). My translation file name is addproduct.fa.xliff. According to the documentation the domain is and "optional way to organize messages into groups". I chose "addproducts". The locale is fa and the loader is xliff. Is this correct now?

Comment: You also need to reference the 'addproduct' domain when you call the `->trans` method. See the example at the end of my answer, above, but replace 'app' with 'addproduct'. And remember to clear the cache (`app/console cache:clear --no-warmup`) after each time you've updated the translations file. :)